# What is the apt equivalent to these dselect commands?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm reading a tutorial on backing up packages from one Ubuntu/Debian server and restoring to another (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ubuntu-and-debian-package-management-essentials#transferring-package-lists-between-systems) that uses dselect as part of the process.

However, wherever I look online everyone seems to say that dselect is deprecated and apt should be used instead, but I'm not sure what the apt equivalent of `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade` is.

Is it really just `sudo apt-get upgrade`? Would I just do:

`sudo dpkg --set-selections < packagelist.txt`

and then

`sudo apt-get upgrade` ? Or is there some extra nuance with `dselect-upgrade` that requires a different apt command to be used to acheive the same results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt-get dselect-upgrade` doesn’t actually use `dselect`, it applies changes made to the `Status` field in the list of available packages. This is what `dselect` used to do (and still does), but it’s also what `dpkg --set-selections` does — so the instructions you’re following are just using the old interface between `dselect` and `apt-get` to get `apt-get` to apply changes made by `dpkg`.

The process goes like this:

- `dpkg --set-selections` updates the package statuses in the list of available packages (stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, based on the available packages in `/var/lib/dpkg/available`), but doesn’t perform any package installations;
- `apt-get dselect-upgrade` resolves the delta between the currently-installed packages and the states requested in the list of available packages, and performs the necessary actions to reconcile the two.

No `dselect` involved!